# i am getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: pandas, typeerror, unsupportedoperation

```py
ratings = pd.read_csv(path/'u.data', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=[user,item,'rating','timestamp']) 
ratings.head()
```

whenever i run this code i am getting this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Post the code not just the traceback

Comment: i posted the code

Comment: `path/'u.data'` means you are dividing the variable `path` by the constant `'u.data'`. If you want to concatenate them, you can use `import os`, then `os.path.join(path, u.data)` (recommended for paths), or do it directly using f-strings such as `f'{path}/u.data'`

Answer (score 0):

Check your file path. It should be `path+'/u.data'` and not `path/'u.data'`. With the latter you're trying to divide a string with another as is evident from the error you get.