# Cannot define path: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, pathlib

I've been facing an issue with defining a directory to use for the function `open()`. Unfortunately, it tells me that there is a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`. How can I define in what folder to put the file without using a forward slash? I tried a backslash, but that prompted another error. I checked out a similar post's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279071/18084172), but I got an error saying `SyntaxError: expected ':'`.

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
dragonfly = input("name?")
directory = pathlib.Path("insects")
directory.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
r = "this is a test"
with open("insects" / f'{dragonfly}.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(r)
```

Comment: If you want to use the slash operator as a directory separator, I believe at least one of the directories must be a `Path` object.  They can't both be strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the entire path in the f-string:

```
with open(f'insects/{dragonfly}.pdf', 'wb')
```